Avoid parent record locking
Our customer are using the standards apis to insert record of different types that have the same parent record.
UPDATE : Two of these records are the detail record of a MDR while the others are linked to the parent using lookup relationship.
Everything works fine until they perform multiple inserts in a short time window what trigger an "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW. unable to obtain exclusive access to this record...etc" error.
We want them to be able to perform those insert independently so that they can inserts records in the order they want and whenever they want.
From what i know, the parent record is locked during an insert to avoid his deletion what would trigger a referencing error.

First question is: Since these are different transactions, why do i get this error?
2nd: what would be the most suitable architecture to avoid it?


It is precisely because these are independent transactions you are getting these errors. They can be caused because of master detail relationships (with or without rollups), or lookups with "restrict" deletion constraint (rather than "set null"), or because of some custom automation that happens during the insert. If these are master detail children you need to make sure you address a given parent's child records together in a single transaction. If the parent is lookup, you might change the deletion constraint to "set null" then add a custom trigger on parent deletion that deletes children.

When you say "If these are master detail children you need to make sure you address a given parent's child records together in a single transaction" you mean the insert of the different child records need to be part of the same transaction?

Does the records which are getting inserted have any automations around it? Like heavy triggers, flows etc?
For these scenarios there are no exact workarounds. The second transaction can only wait 10 seconds for the lock to be released, if the lock is not released within that time, the second transaction will fail.

For these scenarios, we generally retry the composite/standard api, until the request succeeds or to a limit of 5 times, with a gap of 5 seconds , if our automations are well defined and cannot be further optimised.

Unfortunately yes there are some heavy logic around one of the child object.

By "If these are master detail children you need to make sure you address a given parent's child records together in a single transaction" I did indeed mean make it part of the same transaction if at all possible.

@Fabien Braconnier The client should retry the transaction. Multiple retries with a backoff strategy is typical. Salesforce has a crappy pessimistic locking scheme, alas.

@identigral you're right that's what i  suggested to them but i think i should also be able to implement a clean logic on SF side, as best practice :)

@Fabien Braconnier In that case you need your own serialization facility. Comments below by Phil and  cropredy are good options to investigate. While that might work, it adds quite a bit of complexity and that could negate much of the benefit of rolling this solution. Retry is the best practice.

I've never implemented this but i'll search for it, thanks!

This system design is required for proper system operation where each transaction is ACID (Atomic, Consistent, Isolated and Durable). Instead, like every other database that is considered reliable, you must work within those limits. Do not allow parent records to have tens of thousands of children (see Avoid Data Skew), have many records all owned by one user (See Ownership Data Skew), and avoid adding so much code and/or customization that your transactions take more than a couple of seconds. By optimizing your database performance, you'll reduce (though not necessarily eliminate) the UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors.

I already read those two articles (but thanks!) the problem is that it happens even if there's only one parent implied: it's not about volumes of data or ownership. The parents object table contains maybe 2k records, same for the children's table. So there's no workaround to avoid this error while letting out client insert records independently?

@FabienBraconnier There is a small, non-zero period of time where the locks won't cause this problem. Unfortunately, any database that needs to write data needs the ability to be Atomic, Consistent, Isolated, and Durable, needs locks. For Salesforce, the parent lock has to do with multiple tables, including sharing, history, etc. The best practice is to keep your transactions as short as possible. Shorter locks means less errors.

@FabienBraconnier Alternatively, you can build code in Apex to make longer, more intentional locks, and then interact with records though that mechanism. Still, the mantra should be to keep your transactions as short as possible. Overlapping edits in a database will corrupt data.

Duly noted, thanks for those inputs guys.  If anyone has a any workaround... feel free to share!

could it be possible to avoid parallel posting? (because that's what cause the issue right?)

@FabienBraconnier developers should definitely try to design systems that avoid concurrent update of records that would cause the problem.

An option to avoid parallel processing is to introduce a middleware that controls a queue used to update Salesforce (or implement the equivalent using some "request-like" records in Salesforce with automation that runs in a serial manner to process these requests). Either way, you have to then consider all record manipulation as async, from the ultimate client perspective, with the client able to deal with failures that are notified back to it (or found through polling Salesforce).

@FabienBraconnier - avoiding parallel processing can be accomplished having the external system publish Platform Events; the Apex trigger handler will not be parallelized (unless you enable the pilot program feature). This gives you more control over concurrency

@cropredy i get the idea on the external system publishing Platform Events what a trigger has to to with this? The notification should be "catch" with a custom REST API isn't it? Am i missing something?

@FabienBraconnier, publishing Platform Events is merely making a REST call by the publisher; the event subscriber is a trigger and serialized

Ok got it, i going to check if this is doable on his side, thanks!
